# How to call other EAR's bean method

Tags: java, ejb, ear

I have two EARs (*EAR-1*, *EAR-2*) in JBOSS application server.
In EAR-2, I have a stateless session bean:

```
TestTimerBean
```

In this bean, I have a method:

> ```
>            startTimer()
> ```

Now I would like to access/call this method: `startTimer()` from *EAR-1*.

Could any one suggest me on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step you have to do is to make a lookup of EJB.

In JBoss you can access using following:

```
context/Bean_Name/remote
```

where context is your ear name the `Bean_Name` is the remote interface.

Hope this help you