# EJB Stateless Bean cannot be found. Injection fails

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, ejb, code-injection

I have two Modules WAR and Business.

I try to inject a stateless bean in web module. But the stateless bean can not be found?

Where is the error? Any Idea??

In Business Module:

```
@Stateless
public class BusinessFacade {

    public void processEntity(final MyEntitiy entity) {
        System.out.println(entity.getName());
    }

}
```

In WAR Module:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    BusinessFacade businessFacade;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The Error:

```
[31.08.12 10:19:38:835 CEST] 00000018 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myproject.business.beans.BusinessFacade
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFieldsImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:544)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.AnnotationConfigurator.fields(AnnotationConfigurator.java:846)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.AnnotationConfigurator.createFacesConfig(AnnotationConfigurator.java:328)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.AnnotationConfigurator.createFacesConfig(AnnotationConfigurator.java:94)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getAnnotationsFacesConfig(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:148)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.getFacesConfigData(DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.java:91)

....
..

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myproject.business.beans.BusinessFacade
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:198)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:646)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:113)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:564)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:564)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:612)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: I think you need add project dependency between business module and war.

Comment: Are they packaged into the same EAR?

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye I defined the dependencies in Pom.xml.

Comment: @zeller Yes they are packaged in the same EAR.

Comment: @Kayser defining in same pom may not be good enough; may be "OK" if you are using mvn to actually package your web app / EAR file.  In the end, what do your deployment descriptors (after packaging) look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what happens:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class BusinessFacade {

    public void processEntity(final MyEntitiy entity) {
       System.out.println(entity.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: Which application server are you using?

Comment: BTW did you clean up every thing and redeployed properly? I had the same issue and solved it with `@LocalBean`! I will check your code again.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do it so simply. This type of injection works between EJBs in the same EAR, but if i remember correctly in JBoss 5.0GA you can't inject an EJB into a Servlet and so on ( you should check if i'm right).

You should tell if you are using an EAR to hold the Web module and the EJB part or they're deployed in some other ways.

Give a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841488/how-to-call-other-ears-bean-method/11841665#11841665) it could help you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Create a interface

```
@Local
public interface BusinessLocal {
    void processEntity(final MyEntitiy entity);
}
```

Implement the interface in your ejb

```
public class BusinessFacade implements BusinessLocal {
...
}
```

And inject the interface.

```
@EJB
BusinessLocal businessFacade;
```